# jQuery Mobile - Disable Clicking Collapsible Header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to be able to disable opening/closing collapsible's in a set, instead the user is going to click a continue button inside of the open element which will do validation and then open the next element when its ready to.  I'm basically using the collapsible set as a wizard.  I have been searching the docs and have found where I can capture an event when the collapse takes place but I can't find how to cancel it.  Any suggestions, or suggestions of other wizard type controls that would do what I'm talking about I would appreciate it!

Comment: If you can capture the event, have you tried stopping further propogation of the event? http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I will take a look at this, if it works I will let you know and you can make it an answer so I can select it.

Comment: I bound the event and set a breakpoint and the code is executing, event is not null so it is getting something, but stopPropagation is not having any effect.  I think maybe I'm only getting a sender and not the actual event, actually in Chrome the collapsible is already shown before the breakpoint is hit, so I think my event binding is happening after the jquery one that expands/collapses the panel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit more research I have finally found an answer to this.  Posting it here in hopes its helpful to anybody else trying to turn an accordion into a wizard.

My collapsible is set up like this:

```
 <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="col1" >
     <h3>Title</h3>
     <p>
         <input type="text" />
         <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="nextClicked(1);" />
     </p>
 </div>
```

To stop the click from working but maintain being able to trigger the expand I use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#col1 h3 a").click(function (event) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

I had tried using preventDefault and stopPropagation but neither of these did it.  Apparently return false does some extra work as well as those two.

Edit: I found out that this works in a browser but does not prevent it on mobile, to prevent it on mobile you also have to capture the tap event, but be careful, you have to do it on the header and not the entire collapsible or any elements in the collapsible such as buttons will not register either.  This is the code I used:

```
$("#col1 h3").on("tap", function (event, ui) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Confirmed, adding 'return false' did the trick for me too vs. using preventDefault(). . . thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Changing

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
```

to

```
<div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-disabled">
```

disables the header both graphically and functionally for me.

See http://jsfiddle.net/NY63z/